# Troubling accessing media on AWS S3, ERROR 403, on Django app

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having trouble accessing media files uploaded on AWS S3 for my Django app.
I was attempting to use Boto3 and Django-Storages libraries and followed these tutorials:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kt3ZtW9MXhw

Both the Django Admin website and my front-end website are not able to load any of the static and media content. The Django admin is rendered without any CSS, and similarly my front-end has no images.
[image]

[image]

AWS Configurations were added to the settings.py file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "me-south-1"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'jooler-mea'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'joole.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_STATIC_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'media'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'joole.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

The relevant storages in storage_backends.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_STATIC_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = False
```

I added S3FullAccess:
[image]

The files are successfully uploading to the AWS website, I can download the files from there to my computer.
[image]
I tried playing around with CORS and custom policies but have not been successful. I've hit a dead end or not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make a public access for your AWS S3 bucket.

Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html

This is different from the permissions that you released according to your question (for your own user).

Or try placing the following bucket policy. See the screenshot. Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2020-09-03",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::jooler-mea/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you send a print from AWS of the list of files in your bucket?

Comment: I added a photo in the original question, I cant paste an image into the comments. Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer... Try to place a bucket policy manually.

Comment: Once you do it, you will probably see the "Public" label as in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah! Done! Half the media loaded now. This mean that anyone can access the media?